# I’m looking to build a non-electrolytic capacitor. Can activated carbon work as my plate material instead of metal?

Tags: capacitor

I always see non-electrolytic capacitors using aluminum as their plate material. But there are these special electrolytic capacitors with activated carbon as the plate material called super caps.

I want to use that activated carbon in my capacitor because it’s better than metal because of the high surface area. I’d like to build mine without an electrolyte, with just an ordinary dielectric inbetween.

Would this activated carbon capacitor work if there was no electrolyte? Would activated carbon work in non-electrolytic capacitors just like the capacitors that use metal as the plate material?

I want to use either copper or activated carbon for my capacitor; it’s just I would prefer activated carbon because it’s cheaper and has a higher surface area. I don’t want a electrolytic one, that’s all.

Comment: It seems you've asked this before, and you've gotten the same answers: It's pointless, no, the surface area in itself does not help, you need to make the other electrode *conformant* with your porous activated carbon electrode. You didn't accept an  answer. Is it possible you simply want your (sadly incorrect) preconceptions to be validated, not actual technically and physically correct answers?

Comment: what do you think the high surface area gets you without an electrolyte? It will only contact a sheet of dielectric at a few high points...

Answer (score 2):

Good username for this question!

You win nothing by having high surface area of one electrode if you don't bring the other other electrode close to that surface – which is exactly what the electrolyte in electrolytic caps is: the other electrode to the porous metal electrode. Metal, because metal can form an insulating oxide layer, which is good enough a dielectric.

You seem to have forgotten the basics of how a capacitor works in the challenge of building one! It works because there's an electrical field strength between the electrodes, which is

1. inversely proportional to the distance of both electrodes
2. proportional to the voltage between the electrodes.

Now, "mentally" integrate your distance to, say, an insulated flat electrode simply put as plate on top  over all your carbon "dust" surface: The parts of the dust that are a bit further away from that plate simply do not contribute much to the field strength. On the other hand, while putting any changing voltage across the gap, you will have ohmic losses in your activated carbon (because that means its not a solid brick of anthracite, these are large). So, there's a lot of voltage loss. Congratulations, by using a complicated material, you just made your capacitor much worse. (but due to the dependency on compression of the dust, it might work OK-ish as a microphone. I'm sure you want your capacitors to be microphones, in secret!)

So, no, you win nothing with activated carbon, especially since you can't make a good, continously-conducting electrode out of it. And, your idea of having high surface but not using it seems to put your whole approach into question.

> I'm wanting to use either copper or activated carbon for my capacitor, it’s just I would prefer activated carbon because it’s cheaper and has a higher surface area.

Copper is the way to go. Copper film is way cheaper per useful capacitor plate area!

If you want high surface, buy a large piece plastic film (typically, mylar) coated on one side with a thin layer metal (often, aluminium), cut it in half, giving you the two electrodes you need. Now, put them on top of each other (of course, uncoated side on metal side, so that there's a dielectric in between the electrodes). Fold or roll - congratulations, you made a cheap capacitor. A film capacitor!

Again, surface area doesn't help you, if you cannot bring the other electrode any closer to the surface. That, and only that, is why you'd want a porous material in capacitors, and that requires the other electrode to be conducting and space-filling (i.e., an electrolyte). If you don't want an electrolyte, you don't want a porous electrode.

Comment: Both plates of the capacitor would be made of the same material. I’m not sure why you would assume I would only make one plate out of a certain material.

Comment: how would that help, again? two porous electrodes are even worse than just one.

Comment: Well imagine a metal square then imagine one with a high porosity. The second one would have a higher surface area and will be able to hold A LOT more charge.

Comment: Why do you think the surface area of the electrode is actually beneficial? Maybe I'm just missing something, and I'd need you to explain what the working principle of your capacitor would me. Maybe even drawing a cut (or whatever is useful for illustration) of your proposed capacitor design and adding it to your question could help :)

Comment: @Electrode it would *not* hold a lot more charge. See my answer! The surface area of a capacitor electrode in itself doesn't matter. What matters is the integral of area divided by distance to other electrode.

Comment: In the arv ufo they were using sintered copper powder with glass as the dielectric. If they used an electrolyte or basic sheet metal opposed to highly specialized high surface powder electrode plates they would never have achieved warp.  [Edited:RM]

Comment: Yes surface area divided by the distance in between the plates.

Comment: Why are you imagining such a thin dielectric? Surface area does matter. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: OK, I stop here. "Warp", "ARV UFO": these don't exist, they are conspiracy theory things, you not understanding the difference between the area integral between point-wise voltage divided by distance and the overall surface area divided by mean distance simply means you're removed from reality, and arguing  based on physics makes no sense. Surface area in itself does not matter. Again, physics basics, not make-a-wish UFO physics is what counts!

Comment: “Surface area does not matter” please explain. [Edited: RM]

Comment: Puthoff has his own company and proof of his testimony and he’s an electrical engineer and he’s worked with alcubierre on his warp drive. I guess you like skinny foil so much you forgot how science works. And “surface area doesn’t matter”

Comment: Oh dear. You're really into this scam. OK, I'm an electrical engineer, too. (and I have my own business, consulting customers on technical issues, as well.) So, my credentials are as good as those of whoever Puthoff is. But: I'm not trying to sell "warp technology" to the public. So what I write is incredibly much more credible, to other engineers, than whatever he says, sorry.

Comment: You’re bluffing. Is to the star academy not real too is thinking that’s real “buying in”? The army made a public announcement online about the department of defense contract with Tom Delonge.

Comment: You literally said “surface area doesn’t matter if you want more charge” [Edited: RM]

Comment: @Electrode    This comment thread has  significantly violated the site's code of conduct. Personal abuse and general name calling is completely unacceptable. Any repeat will result in account restriction. I have copied the prior thread to chat for reference. Poor behaviour is equally unacceptable there. I have edited rather than deleting a number of comments to try to preserve the thread. [Old material here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138823/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-im-looking-to-build-a-non-electrolytic-ca).

Comment: @Electrode  Marcus's comments about area not being important BY ITSELF have been qualified in all cases. Reading what he says in context should allow you to understand what he is saying.

Comment: I was out grocery shopping. I did not expect things to become this personally... interesting. Thank you, Russel, you've handled this very gracefully. (imho)

Comment: @Electrode For a capacitor to have increased capacitace produced by increasing the surface area per plate area of one electrode, the other electrode must have equal area and the two plates must be a mimimal distance apart. If you have two plates with a given separation and increase the area of both, if the  separation increases as a consequence of area increase the increased capacitance will NOT be proportional to area increase - and may be much lower. Electriolytic capacitors achieve this by having an electrolyte-electrode which cclosely conforms to the other electrode. In the absence ...

Comment: ... of an electolyte some other means is required to maintain the very low inter-electrode distances.